# How to generate .res file containing icons runtime

Tags: c#, winapi, icons, resource-files, rc.exe

i need to make the res runtime and it need to contain some icons i have in a list in my application.
the res file has to be placed in a project "Resource File" field. so it needs to be win32 compatable.

i so fa tried to:

- create a .resx file runtime containing the icons and i converted it to a
  .resources file with ResGen.exe but i ended up in a dead end.
- i tried to fit the .resx i created in the project "Resource File" but it 
  gives an error saying "the selected file is not a valid Win32 resource file".
- i also tried to create a .rc file but i can't figure ut how to properly use
  rc.exe to compile it in a .res file so an other dead end as well...

do you have any idea of how i can achieve this?

if i try to compile a .rc file i get this output:

`Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler, Version 5.1.2264.1 - Build 2264`

`Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. 1985-1998. All rights reserved.`

`Using codepage 1252 as default`

`Creating rc - ResourceFile.res`

`RC: RCPP -CP 1252 -f C:\Users\itis\Desktop\RCa18040 -g C:\Users\itis\Desktop\RDa18040 -DRC_INVOKED -D_WIN32 -pc\:/ -E -I C:\Users\itis\Desktop\ -I .`

`C:\Users\itis\Desktop\_mingw.h(51) : error RC2188: #error :  ERROR: You must use a GNU Compiler.`

`C:\Users\itis\Desktop\_mingw.h(55) : error RC2188: #error :  ERROR: You must use a GNU Compiler version >= 3.4.5.`

`C:\Users\itis\Desktop\afxres.h(34) : fatal error RC1015: cannot open include file 'windows.h'.`

`Premere un tasto per continuare . . .`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [rc.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381055(v=vs.85).aspx) to compile a [.rc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381018(v=vs.85).aspx) file is the normal way to create a .res file.

A .rc file might be as simple as this:

```
1 ICON "myicon1.ico"
2 ICON "myicon2.ico"
```

Comment: Just saying it does not work is not helpful. I know it works if you do it correctly. What errors are you getting?

Comment: sorry it's just that i'm trying to post the code i have in one of the .rc files but it looks awful

Comment: You seem to be mixing MinGW and Microsoft toolchains, don't do that. A .rc file does not need any #include lines if you only need a couple of icons.

Comment: thank you so much!
i don't know why it didn't worked before: i did try something like it but by not working i simply thought it would have been a way more complicated thing...
but now it works perfectly!